# How to make a semi-transparent Navigation Bar in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I've seen several posts discussing how to make a transparent Navbar in SwiftUI, but none on how to make a semi-transparent one, which is surprising to me as its a very common patter on Apple's default apps. For example the Notes app:

[image]

You can see the drawing through the NavBar. Anyone know how to do this, ideally in a way which works in light/dark mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you just need to add translucency settings in your SwiftUI view

[image: demo1]

```
init() {
  UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
}
```

alternate is to reset appearance completely, like

[image: demo2]

```
init() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
}
```

Demo prepared and tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: Your second solution is absolutely perfect, thank you very very much, I've been looking for how to do this for long time! One last question, where are you placing this code? I've placed it in `SceneDelegate.scene`, but I've noticed you wrote it in `init()`, is this some new iOS14 stuff?

Comment: I placed it in init of ContentView just for demo, you can place it wherever it works for you, but before NavigationView created.

Comment: Second solution is a charm!