# Add Opacity to NavigationBar SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view inside of a navigation bar that I am using as a photo preview. I'd like to mimic the Photo's app behavior, and have the image extend past the navigation bar, with the contents blurred by the navigation bar in the background. This picture illustrates what I'm looking to replicate (Red Bar is blocking location of photo)

[image: Desired Behavior]

However, when I extend the View to disregard the safe areas, the navigation bar is fully transparent, and the photo is not blurred at all.

[image: Current App Behavior]

I've noticed on the parent view (`LazyVGrid` in a `ScrollView`) when scrolling the view under the navigation bar, the navigation bar has my desired effect.

[image: Scroll View Behavior]

Is there any way to force this behavior when the view in not in a `ScrollView`?

Here is my code for the photo preview view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PhotoDetailView: View {
    var photo: Photo
    @State var isNavbarHidden: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(minWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/,maxWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.infinity/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, minHeight: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/,maxHeight: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.infinity/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .foregroundColor(isNavbarHidden ? .black : Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            Image(data: photo.imageData, placeholder: "No Image")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
//        .navigationBarHidden(isNavbarHidden)
        .navigationBarTitle("Test Title", displayMode: .inline)
        .onTapGesture(count: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, perform: {
            withAnimation {
                isNavbarHidden.toggle()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64074534/12299030?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me, however I can't figure out where to put the `init`

Comment: In the view where NavigationView created (ie. before it is created)

Comment: So it does change the view like illustrated there, but only after content is moved behind it manually like the current behavior. I want it to have the translucency by default without user interaction.